# How to use the names in a list to access a dataframe column

Tags: r

I have two lists and a dataframe. The columns in the dataframe have the same names as the entries in the list.  The dataframe has other columns as well, other than the ones specified in the lists

```
category.list <- c('Reserve_Book','choicepriv_and_points','Latency_freeze_load','signin','gift_card','mystery_gift','credit_card','call_support','account')
crosstab.list <- c('browser','OS','Device','comment_cat','comment_focus','recommend')
```

Now, how do I iterate through the elements in the list and use them to access the dataframe columns?
Below is the code, I am trying but I am getting errors while trying to access the dataframe column via the iterator variable.

```
for (i in category.list){
  for (j in crosstab.list){  
  ftable(dataframe[j]~dataframe[i])
  }
}
```

Comment: An [example of your data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2005219) would be helpful, as well as the text of your error

Comment: @EdwardR.Mazurek agreed, but in this case it's a basic typo in the column selection

Comment: Use `[[`, i.e. `dataframe[[j]]`. There may also be more R-idiomatic approaches than the nested for loop

Comment: Sorry, [[ is not giving an error , not showing any output either

Comment: Output is automatically hidden in a for loop. If you want it to print, then `print()` it. See `for (i in 1:4) i` vs `for (i in 1:4) print(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to your question, your dataframe references need to specify both which columns are desired and which rows.

`ftable(dataframe[j]~dataframe[i])`

needs to be

`ftable(dataframe[,j]~dataframe[,i])`

Note the addition of commas

Comment: I added the commas, but it is resulting in nothing. No error as well as no output

Comment: Yep, doesn't do much for me either :) But that wasn't what your question was about. My answer just addresses the R errors you were getting

Comment: What result are you expecting? your are not saving results in your `for` loop anywhere, neither you print them.